# Read strings from a file

Tags: c, string, io

```
 FILE *fp;
char name[50];
fp=fopen("stu.txt","r");
while(fgets(name,50,fp)!=NULL)
{

    printf(" %s",name);
    fgets(name,50,fp);

}
fclose(fp);
```

In my file there are 4 names in 4 different lines but the output only displays the 1st and the 3rd name.What's wrong?I know it's very basic but this has taken up a lot of my time.

Comment: Remove the second `fgets(name,50,fp);`

Comment: The `while` loop condition does not specify some condition that will cause the loop to terminate whenever it happens inside the body -- it's an expression that is actually evaluated before each (potential) loop pass to decide whether to execute the loop body (which happens if the result is non-zero).  Putting `fgets()` in the loop condition will call it when the condition is checked before each loop pass... and the `fgets()` inside the loop body is independent of it (your loop only ends when the `fgets()` call in the condition returns `NULL`, but not when the one in the loop body does).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're (f)getting in the `while` statement **and** inside the loop block, so you're advancing the file position without utilizing what you've read in the internal call. Try this:

```
while(fgets(name,50,fp)!=NULL)
{
  printf(" %s",name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `fgets` from the body of the loop. The `fgets` in the `while` expression already does the work.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{

   FILE *fp;
   int c;

   fp = fopen("file.txt","r");
   while(1)
   {
      c = fgetc(fp);
      if( feof(fp) )
      {
         break;
      }
      printf("%c", c);
   }
   fclose(fp);
   return(0);
   }
```

Comment: OP's code was line-based. Yours is character-based.

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

string sLine = "";
ifstream infile;

infile.open("temp.txt");

while (!infile.eof())
{
getline(infile, sLine);
cout << sLine << endl;
}

infile.close();
cout << "Read file completed!!" << endl;

return a.exec();
}
# crdeit apolo chung

Comment: OP's code is C (and the question tagged as such). The code in your comment is C++. And it prints the last line twice.